# How to execute a command on cmd of another system in same network

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt, remote-access

How can I execute a command in `cmd` of another computer which is in the same network without any help of software like `PsExec`.
I have the system name and the credentials to login to the system.
IS there any way to do this using **command prompt** or with **PowerShell**

Thanks for any helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using WinRM and Invoke-Command cmdlet. Read more about it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

It allows you to write something like:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -Credential domain01\user01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WMI:

```
 $WMI_Params = 
  @{
     Class        = 'Win32_Process'
     Name         = 'Create'
     ArgumentList = 'Notepad.exe'
     Credential    = $Creds
   }


Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
 { Invoke-WmiMethod @WMIParams -ComputerName $Computer }
```